# tf.GradientTape giving None gradient while writing custom training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent, gradienttape

I'm trying to write a custom training loop. Here is a sample code of what I'm trying to do. I have two training parameter and one parameter is updating another parameter. See the code below:

```
x1 = tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=float)
x2 = tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=float)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    n = x2 + 4
    x1.assign(n)
    x = x1 + 1
    y = x**2
    val = tape.gradient(y, [x1, x2])
    for v in val:
        print(v)
```

and the output is

```
tf.Tensor(12.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
None
```

It seems like GradientTape is not watching the first(x2) parameter. Both parameter is `tf.Variable` type, so GradientTape should watch both the parameter. I also tried `tape.watch(x2)`, which is also not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#getting_a_gradient_of_none) regarding a gradient of `None`. To get the gradients for `x1`, you have to track `x` with `tape.watch(x)`:

```
x1 = tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=float)
x2 = tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=float)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    n = x2 + 4
    x1.assign(n)
    x = x1 + 1
    tape.watch(x)
    y = x**2

dv0, dv1 = tape.gradient(y, [x1, x2])
print(dv0)
print(dv1)
```

However, regarding `x2`, the output `y` is not connected to `x2` at all, since `x1.assign(n)` does not seem to be  tracked and that is why the gradient is None. This is consistent with the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#4_took_gradients_through_a_stateful_object):

> State stops gradients. When you read from a stateful object, the tape can only observe the current state, not the history that lead to it.
>
> A tf.Tensor is immutable. You can't change a tensor once it's created.
> It has a value, but no state. All the operations discussed so far are
> also stateless: the output of a tf.matmul only depends on its inputs.
>
> A tf.Variable has internal state—its value. When you use the variable,
> the state is read. It's normal to calculate a gradient with respect to
> a variable, but the variable's state blocks gradient calculations from
> going farther back

If, for example, you do something like this:

```
x1 = tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=float)
x2 = tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=float)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    n = x2 + 4
    x1 = n
    x = x1 + 1
    tape.watch(x)
    y = x**2 

dv0, dv1 = tape.gradient(y, [x1, x2])
```

It should work.